# Migrate persistentStoreCoordinator sqlite file to new name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I was attempting to troubleshoot an issue with me sqlite file I realized that in my AppDelegate had an error.

```
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
```

I want change the file name to match the app name but I don't want to lose the current data in the `SingleViewCoreData.sqlite` file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I was able to solve the issue also this is all **Swift 3.1**

```
var pURL: URL?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    checkForOldStore()
    return true
}
```

Then I edited the persistentStoreCoordinator section.

```
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
//        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        let url = self.pURL // ADDED THIS CODE WHICH REPLACED CODE FROM ABOVE.
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
        } catch {
```

With the following code I first check if the old sqlite file exists with the `checkForOldStore()`.  Note that I set the pURL to equal what the old setting was on the `persistentStoreCoordinator` if the file exists before calling the `migrateStore()`. And because the `checkForOldStore()` still runs every time the app starts and now that the file doesn't exists I set the `pURL` to the new file name.

```
    func checkForOldStore() {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")?.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
        pURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        migrateStore()
    } else {
        pURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("NewName.sqlite")
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
    }
}
```

At the end of the `migrateStore()` I call the `remvoeOldDB` for each of the old sqlite files.

```
func migrateStore() {
    // migrate current store from one URL to another
    // write out the current store URL before the migration
    var storeURL: URL? = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last?.url
    print("Current Store URL (before migration): \(String(describing: storeURL?.description))")
    // grab the current store
    let currentStore: NSPersistentStore? = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last
    // create a new URL
    let newStoreURL: URL? = applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("NewName.sqlite")
    // setup new options dictionary if necessary
    // migrate current store to new URL
    _ = try? persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(currentStore!, to: newStoreURL!, options: nil, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    // and to check we're on the new store, write out tha URL again
    storeURL = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last?.url
    print("Current Store URL (after migration): \(String(describing: storeURL?.description))")
    removeOldDB(itemName: "SingleViewCoreData", fileExtension: "sqlite")
    removeOldDB(itemName: "SingleViewCoreData", fileExtension: "sqlite-shm")
    removeOldDB(itemName: "SingleViewCoreData", fileExtension: "sqlite-wal")

}

func removeOldDB(itemName:String, fileExtension: String) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    guard let dirPath = paths.first else {
        return
    }
    let filePath = "\(dirPath)/\(itemName).\(fileExtension)"
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```